# SharePoint 2016 Visual Web Part Deployment using Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, sharepoint-2016

I have `SharePoint 2016` and `Visual Studio 2015` installed on server. I am creating simple "Hello World" Visual Web part but while deploying I am getting error:

```
Severity Code
Description Project
File Line
Suppression State
Error Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.
VisualWebPartProject2_test15Mar
```

Please help me to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Did you create Feature in the Sharepoint project? If no, please create Feature (for instance Site scoped) and add the Visual Web Part as an item in the Feature. Then do the following steps:

1. Select Sharepoint Project and in the Properties pane check if Site Url is correctly set up
2. Clean Solution in Visual Studio
3. Rebuild Solution
4. Deploy Solution